# unix -- get number of business days

Tags: date, unix, calendar

I'm using AIX with the ksh.  I'm trying to calculate the number of business days in a month.  I was trying to use AWK but I'm hung up now.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
cal | awk '{print $2, $3, $4, $5, $6} | awk 'NR > 2'
```

Here's the normal output (for current date/time) for cal:

```
        April 2014
Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat
         1   2   3   4   5
 6   7   8   9  10  11  12
13  14  15  16  17  18  19
20  21  22  23  24  25  26
27  28  29  30
```

Here's what I'm getting with that script:

```
2 3 4 5
7 8 9 10 11
14 15 16 17 18
21 22 23 24 25
28 29 30
```

My plan is to, in the end, read these lines into a c program and output the total weekdays (right now we're not worried about holidays on normal business days).

As you can see here, since the 3rd line of output is only 5 columns itself, it's dropping the 1st business day of that week.  Maybe I'm going about this whole thing wrong -- if there's another way to do this on the Unix operating system or through C: I have no sentimental attachment to "cal" and "awk" (not yet anyway).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This can make it:

```
cal -h | cut -c 4-17 | tail -n +3  | wc -w
```

#### Explanation

`cal` shows line on columns of 4 characters. `-h` turns off highlighting of today.

```
     April 2014       
Su Mo Tu We Th Fr Sa  
       1  2  3  4  5  
 6  7  8  9 10 11 12  
13 14 15 16 17 18 19  
20 21 22 23 24 25 26  
27 28 29 30
```

Since Sunday is first column and Saturday the last one, it is a matter of extracting the numbers in between character 4 and 17:

```
$ cal -h | cut -c 4-17 
  April 2014  
Mo Tu We Th Fr
    1  2  3  4
 7  8  9 10 11
14 15 16 17 18
21 22 23 24 25
28 29 30
```

And then remove the two first lines:

```
$ cal -h | cut -c 4-17 | tail -n +3  
    1  2  3  4
 7  8  9 10 11
14 15 16 17 18
21 22 23 24 25
28 29 30
```

And then count the number of words:

```
$ cal -h | cut -c 4-17 | tail -n +3  | wc -w
22
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  Since my system (AIX) prints out three character days of the week, I used 'cut -c5-24' which got me 22 days.  Not sure why the 18th isn't coming up on your system?  Maybe because it's Good Friday?  Any, thanks a lot -- I'd +1 you, but I'm not there yet

Comment: Oh, 18 wasn't appearing because the highlighting of today (17) was messing the data. Or maybe it is because it is a Saint day, yes!! I updated using `cal -h` to remove the highlighting. Good to read it was useful to you, now we know we are working 22 days this month :D

Comment: Unfortunately, I've known for 14 business days now haha -- but thanks to you, sir, AIX will take care of that input now and I don't have to worry about it! (And March had 20, in case you were interested. I won't forget that very soon either.)

Comment: And I now have enough "rep" -- so +1

Comment: Nice! In fact I dug a little in `man cal` and found out you can for example say `cal Feb 1975`. So we can check how many days we are working every single month. `cal Feb 1975 -h | cut -c 4-17 | tail -n +3  | wc -w` and so on :)

Comment: And so begins our world domination . . . Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To calculate working days of month, until today:

```
TODAY=\`date +%d\`

WDAYS=\`ncal -h | grep -vE "^S|^ |^$" | sed "s/[[:alpha:]]//g" | fmt -w 1 |  sort -n | grep $TODAY -B 33 | wc -l\`

echo $WDAYS
```